# WPF: Use PriorityBinding for DisplayMemberBinding in GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have set a `DisplayMemberBinding` for a `GridViewColumn` in WPF.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resx:TextResources.ExcutionTimesHeaderErrorType}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Exception, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource typeConverter}, FallbackValue='---'}"/>
```

The `typeConverter` 'imitates' the `Exception.GetType()` extension to show the type of the exception as string in the Gui. In case there is no exception and this value is null I want to output another property in this column. Now I want to use `PriorityBinding` as for the `DisplayMemberBinding`, but neither `GridViewColumn` does except `PriorityBinding` as a 'sub-element', nor is it possible to use the `DisplayMemberBinding` attribute as 'sub-element'. Is there a way of using `PriorityBinding` for a `GridViewColumn` like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resx:TextResources.ExcutionTimesHeaderErrorType}">
    <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="Exception" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource typeConverter}" IsAsync="True" />
        <Binding Path="AnotherProperty" IsAsync="True" />
    </PriorityBinding>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**EDIT**

I changed my code to the suggestion of "ASh" below, but it does not work:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resx:TextResources.ExcutionTimesHeaderErrorType}">
    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
        <PriorityBinding  FallbackValue="-*-">
            <Binding Path="Exception" Converter="{StaticResource typeConverter}" Mode="OneWay" IsAsync="True"/>
            <Binding Path="Comment" FallbackValue="---"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The display value is empty, if the `Exception` property is null. I checked if the second binding property "comment" is set and it is.

These two bindings work properly:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resx:TextResources.ExcutionTimesHeaderComment}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comment, FallbackValue='---'}"/>

<GridViewColumn Header="test2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Exception, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource typeConverter}, FallbackValue='---'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `<GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>` tag:

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
        <PriorityBinding>
           <Binding Path="Exception" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource typeConverter}" IsAsync="True" />
           <Binding Path="AnotherProperty" IsAsync="True" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
</GridViewColumn>
```

GridViewColumn is marked with ContentProperty attribute and content property is Header: `[ContentProperty("Header")]`. So the inner content of `<GridViewColumn>` tag without `GridViewColumn.` prefix should be assigned to Header property

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've implemented it the way you supposed, but it does not work correctly. If the "Exception-Binding" is null, it does not show any value, even though I defined fallbackValues for the second binding and the priority binding. I edited my post above.

Comment: @RobinBreusch, i guess, if Exception is null and converter returns null or empty string, then PriorityBinding accept it as a valid value and doesn't use Anotherproperty binding (info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6). try return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` from converter if exception is null